# Excel autofilter dates in month period

Tags: vba, excel

The following code filters a range of dates by the dates in August

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$29:$CG$3582").AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodAugust, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

How do I make this code dynamic so that I can filter the range by any month (e.g. month(today()))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing...

```
Function GetDatesInPeriodConst(month As Long)
    GetDatesInPeriodConst = 20 + month
    '(January is number 21)
End Function
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$29:$CG$3582").AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:= _
GetDatesInPeriodConst(month(Date)), Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Criteria2`, this is a bit cryptic though.  Pass `Array(1, datestring)`, where 1 will filter the entire month of that date, and the datestring must be in m/d/y format.
(0 = entire year, 2 = day, and some more, as discussed [somewhere here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/autofilter-criteria-with-xlfiltervalues-and-dates/90da7c5a-c813-4182-9849-c57ab72dac63)).

```
Dim s As String
s = Format(Now, "MM""/""dd""/""yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$29:$CG$3582").AutoFilter _
    Field:=18, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
    Criteria2:=Array(1, s)
```